# Order By No me devuelve el ultimo valor MVC

Tags: mvc

MVC - ¿Por qué este código no me devuelve el último valor, sino que me devuelve el valor más grande?

```
 int LastRegister = db.suma1.OrderByDescending(x => x.suma).First().suma;
```

Answer (score 1):

Porque estás ordenando en descendente sobre todas tus sumas, no entre los registros.

Puedes llamarlo por el id o tu contador

```
int LastRegister = db.suma1.OrderByDescending(x => x.id).First().suma;
```

O usar dieractamente la funcion de ultimo

```
int LastRegister = db.suma1.LastorDefault().suma;
```